# what's wrong with this MySQL prepared statement? "unkown column in where clause"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I'm using a prepared statement with this SQL code:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `securities` WHERE `symbol`=? AND `type`=`C`
```

but I keep getting this error when I execute it:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'C' in 'where clause'
```

The table is set up like this:

```
+--------+-----------------------+------+------+
| symbol | name                  | type | used |
+--------+-----------------------+------+------+
| AED    | UAE Dirham            | C    | 0    |
| ALL    | Albanian Lek          | C    | 0    |
| ANG    | Neth Antilles Guilder | C    | 0    |
| ARS    | Argentine Peso        | C    | 0    |
| AUD    | Australian Dollar     | C    | 0    |
| AWG    | Aruba Florin          | C    | 0    |
| BBD    | Barbados Dollar       | C    | 0    |
| BDT    | Bangladesh Taka       | C    | 0    |
| BGN    | Bulgarian Lev         | C    | 0    |
| BHD    | Bahraini Dinar        | C    | 0    |
+--------+-----------------------+------+------+
```

and I'm trying to query *just* the name from it. How can I fix this error? The code that involves binding a value is too long to post, but basically, it executes the prepared statement with `array($symbol)`. Is there an SQL error that I'm missing?

Comment: Just seen your edit. What error message do you get when you use 'C' (or "C").

Comment: See my comment below; when I tried using single quotes, I wasn't escaping them properly elsewhere in my PHP code, which generated the same message. It' fixed now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the value `C` enclosed in backticks. This should only be done for column and table names, not values.

Change it to quotes and it should work:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `securities` WHERE `symbol`=? AND `type`='C'
```

Comment: I wasn't escaping my single quotes properly, which is why when I originally tried it with single quotes, it didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help! Wouldn't be the first time I've done that, either. :)

Answer (score 2):

things in backticks are assumed to be column/table names in MySQL. What your asking MySQL to do there is return all the rows where the value in the type column is the same as is in the C column, what you actually wanted was a single (or double) quote. ie.

```
SELECT `name` FROM `securities` WHERE `symbol`=? AND `type`='C'
```